# Make an eco friendly cleaning product

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am trying to make an eco-friendly cleaning product and want some advice on what the best chemicals are to use.

I plan to make a laundry detergent and all purpose cleaner. I want both to be free from toxins and harmful chemicals. I would also like to use essential oils. Even better and kinder on the skin a honey or milk product included. **Can this be done?** I cannot find any cleaning products so far with milk or honey in.

Comment: I think you need to tell us more about this proposed cleaning product. What do you want to clean?

Answer (score 1):

Making your own soap from oils/fats and sodium or potassium hydroxide is something well described and within the compass of a kitchen chemist. Running an internet search on "making your own soap" produces pages of hits such as this one  https://www.diynatural.com/how-to-make-soap-2/

Laundry detergents are a different matter as the Wikipedia entry makes clear https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laundry_detergent
Soaps are less effective for this and particularly struggle with hard water. Modern laundry detergents contain multiple ingredients such as alkylbenzenesulfonates which are beyond the kitchen chemist. They also contain bleaches based on salts of peracids  (typically perborate and percarbonate) which are not readily available and, I think, you would consider toxic.